# Setting up Core Data object relations within an efficient performance (Large Data Set)

Tags: iphone, core-data, sqlite, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm have to deal with to import large dateset into Core Data (~15 000 recods). But the problem is setting up the relations that takes a lot of time maybe more than 10 minutes. Because each records have 3 or more relations that i have to fetch their related object from MOC. With basic calculation i have to perform 45.000 fetch request while the number of objects in MOC is being populating. I have read some topics about and mostly it is suggested to migrate from Core Data to SQLite. But sure it takes time and lots of modification in code. Is there anyway to solve this without giving up Core Data. Is it possible to insert record into sqlite DB of Core Data directly?

\Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With that many records being saved I would say your best bet is to make the best user  experience out of it. Let them know it will take awhile.

What kind of relationships are you building? Are you setting both sides of the relationship or just one?

I'd say the best improvement you'll get is to figure out the cleanest way to fetch everything. And if you can, only save the context at the end instead of every time (if you are doing that).

Another alternative might be to not do the relationship building until you need it.

But without code, it is hard to give suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Hi @Ryan thanks for your response. After have discussion with one of the developer from Apple Technical Support, I removed all relationships from model and keep going with keeping unique id of relations as you suggested.